# Record list component doesn't show external objects in scratch org

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, customer-community, lightning-community, community-builder

I'm trying to use the record list component in a Community with an external object but I can't see it in the list. I can't see in a scratch org but it's possible to see it in my Dev Hub. Also, I'm using the external object in a custom component and showing the data without any issues.

[image]

Is it possible that I'm missing something?

Comment: Just to confirm, the external object is deployed in your Scratch Org, right?

Comment: Yes, it's deployed and I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define tab for that custom object. Setup > Tabs > New, choose icon etc..